# How to unhook SSDT hooks and make them gat away?

Tags: windows, hook, rootkit

I'm working on a rootkit and reversing it.I'm supposing to write my anti-rk specific for this kind of rootkit.The rootkit hooks some kernel-mode functions that can't be unhooked from user-mode, or if I unhook them from user-mode they will not get away and will be back.
So what's your suggestions?

Comment: The rootkit is running in kernel mode, so unless you run at least some of your code in kernel mode as well you're going to be at a serious, probably fatal, disadvantage.  (One possible alternative would be to write code that runs off-line, e.g., while booted from a DVD.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a lot of example code and open source projects out there, which does this. You can refer their source to know SSDT unhooking. Few examples:
https://code.google.com/p/arkitlib/
https://code.google.com/p/oark/